# BigQuery removes fields with Postgres Array during datastream ingestion

Tags: arrays, postgresql, google-bigquery, google-datastream

I have this table named `student_classes`:

```
| id  | name     | class_ids  |
| ----| ---------| -----------|
| 1   | Rebecca  | {1,2,3}    |
| 2   | Roy      | {1,3,4}    |
| 3   | Ted      | {2,4,5}    |
```

`name` is type `text` / string
`class_ids` is type `integer[]`

I created a datastream from PostgreSQL to BigQuery ([following these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/quickstart-replication-to-bigquery)), but when I looked at the table's schema in BigQuery the `class_ids` field was gone and I am not sure why.

I was expecting `class_ids` would get ingested into BigQuery instead of getting dropped.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Official docs list this as a known limitation:

"Datastream doesn't support columns of the Array data types."
https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/sources-postgresql#postgresqlknownlimitations